# ajax get does not work in chrome but does in Firefox

Tags: ajax, jquery

```
var url = "http://opensocial.flixster.com/igoogle/showtimes?date=20111027&postal=23226";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function (html) {
        alert('in success'); // THIS NEVER HAPPENS
    },
    error: function () { return null; }
});
```

The above works in Firefox just fine, but, success function is never triggered in Chrome.  Does anyone know why?  And, any alternatives to make it work in all browsers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried it over on jsbin and works perfectly: http://jsbin.com/eyikac/2/edit#javascript,live

What kind of error does it give? Try to check the [Chrome developer tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html) JavaScript console for error messages.

Comment: I put this on a local .html file, and drag 'n' dropped it into my chrome browser.  nothing happens at all, not even any error message if I do "alert('error')" in the "error:" part. could it be because the url is "file:///C:/Users/ian/Desktop/test.html" ? and chrome is thinking "woah, this is not a legit url" ?

Comment: wait!! good call on the chrome console thing. "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://opensocial.flixster.com/igoogle/showtimes?date=20111027&postal=23226. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: Well yes, I know that chrome has some problems performing ajax requests when running from a static HTML file. Should be this issue here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47416

Comment: that's it.  thanks so much Juri!  I just dropped that html in a simple html file, put it on a domain that I own to test it out, and it works great.

Comment: you're welcome. Running it on a local server works as well. The problem is the file:/// protocol on which they seem to restrict it.